# How to detect when a user leaves a screen when the screen is in a BottomTabNavigator within a StackNavigator in React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm working on a project where I need to know if a user leaves the HomeScreen so that I can save any unsaved changes. My HomeScreen is in a BottomTabNavigator that is contained in a StackScreenNavigator. In addition, the button/tab for the HomeScreen has multiple features. When pressed normally it goes to the HomeScreen, but when held down it  pops up with a screen showing additional screen routes (these are contained within the main StackNavigator). Within the HomeScreen I have tried using:

```
 React.useEffect(() =>
      navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
        console.log('leftHome')
     }),navigation]);
```

and

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', (e) => {
      // Prevent default behavior
      e.preventDefault();
     console.log('leftHome')
    });
    return unsubscribe;
   }, [navigation]);
```

While within the tabNavigation I've tried:

```
 <Tab.Screen name="Home" 
    component={HomeScreen} 
    listeners={{
    tabPress: (e) => {
    console.log('leftHome')
    }}}
...
```

After finding: "One thing to keep in mind is that you can only listen to events from the immediate navigator with addListener. For example, if you try to add a listener in a screen that's inside a stack that's nested in a tab, it won't get the tabPress event. If you need to listen to an event from a parent navigator, you may use navigation.getParent to get a reference to parent navigator's navigation prop and add a listener.", in the docs, I also tried:

```
   React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.getParent('MyTabs').addListener('tabPress', (e) => {
    console.log('leftHome')
  });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

in my HomeScreen and tried giving both my StackNavigator and my HomeScreenNavigator the 'MyTabs' id. None of these have worked for me. Does anyone know how to get this to work? I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

Navigation.tsx

```
export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={linking}>
      <RootNavigator/>

    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}


const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
function RootNavigator() {

  const { navigate } = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>()
    
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home" 
    >
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="HomeScreen" 
      options= {{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
      component={HomeScreenNavigator}
       />
       
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Splash"
        component={SplashScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Login"
        component={LoginScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Log In"
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Signup"
        component={SignupScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Sign Up"
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="AdditionalTabs" 
      component={AdditionalTabsScreen} 
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


function HomeScreenNavigator() {
  const { navigate } = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>()

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Tab1" 
          component={Tab1Screen} 
       />
       <Tab.Screen name="Tab2" 
         component={Tab2Screen} 
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" 
      component={HomeScreen} 
      options={({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarButton: (props) => (
          <View  {...props}>
          <Pressable
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
          onLongPress={() => navigation.navigate('AdditionalTabs')}
          >
          </Pressable>
          </View>
        ),
      })}        
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Tab3" 
         component={Tab3Screen} 
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Tab4" 
         component={TabNavigator2}
     />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

function TabNavigator2() {
  const { navigate } = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>()
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Tab5" 
    
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Tab5" component={Tab5Screen} />
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="Tab6" 
      component={Tab6Screen} 
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```